# Get the Last MB of a Text File using Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to display a log file in a textarea.  I just need the last MB of the log file.  How do I get this to just print out?  If it's like a 5MB file, I just want to skip over the first 4MB and print out the last 1 MB of the file.  I was looking into RandomAccessFile, File, and BufferedReader.  I just need an example of how to use these properly, but I keep getting the wrong result.

```
File file = new File("C:\\Windows\\PFRO.log");
RandomAccessFile raFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
byte[] data = new byte[10000000];
raFile.seek(file.length()-1000000);
raFile.read(data, (int) (file.length()-1000000), 1000000);
System.out.println("Here's the log: " + data.toString());
```

I get Here's the log: [B@7852e922
How do I just get the contents?
Thanks!

Comment: Once you get your data into a byte array you could use `System.arraycopy` to copy however much of the last part of the array you want

Comment: I'll look into that!  Thanks Luckyging3r!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about,

```
  BufferedReader raFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
  char[] data = new char[SIZE];
  raFile.skip(file.length() - SIZE);
  raFile.read(data, 0, data.length);
  System.out.println("Here's the log: " + new String(data));
```

Comment: I think you are on to what I'm going for.  For some reason, when it prints out, there is a space between every character.  Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: I think you can add a parameter to the `String()` constructor so that it interprets the char array properly (maybe `UTF16`)

Comment: Thank you for all of your help!  I do appreciate it!  :)